# Как отключить скрипт после однократного срабатываения?

Tags: javascript

Я написал скрипт который при переходе на сайт приветствует пользователя, но я не могу сделать так чтобы он отключался после одного использования

```
var name;
if(confirm("Здраствуйте!")) {
    name = prompt("Напишите ваше имя!");
    alert("Здраствуйте, " + name + "!" + " Спасибо за посещение нашего веб-сайта" + "!")
}
```

Comment: что означает отключался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
if(localStorage.firstTime !== 'false'){
    alert('welcome');
    localStorage.firstTime = false;
}
```

Или нужно привязку `вкл\выкл фичи` к имени сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй создать флаг в storage который будет хранить состояние, исполнился скрипт или нет.

```js
if(!window.localStorage.get("executed")) {
  var name;
  if(confirm("Здраствуйте!")) {
      name = prompt("Напишите ваше имя!");
      alert("Здраствуйте, " + name + "!" + " Спасибо за посещение нашего веб-сайта" + "!")
  }
  window.localStorage.set("executed", 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать либо куки, либо локальные переменные, как пример:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('hello')) {
    var name = prompt("Здраствуйте!\nНапишите ваше имя");
    if (name != 'null') {
        alert("Здраствуйте, " + name + "!" + " Спасибо за посещение нашего веб-сайта" + "!");
        localStorage.setItem('hello', name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!